# How do electrons flow when a capacitor is connected to a battery with certain voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

If there is an insulator between the conducting plates of a capacitor which is connected to a battery, the circuit is open. Since the pathway for electrons to flow is impeded by the insulator, how would a capacitor get charged?

Comment: In other to charge the capacitor in the figure below, the electron from the battery connected to the capacitor flows from

Answer (score 2):

The current flows and charge collects on the capacitor's plates, so in the gap between the plates current is not flowing, but current is still flowing through the rest of the circuit until the capacitor is charged enough (until the voltage across it equals the voltage at the source).

Now here's the kicker - current always flows for some small amount of time in any open circuit. The ends which are not connected act as capacitors, but since the area of the wires is small and the distance between the unconnected ends large, the capacitance is low and very little charge collects on those ends. But it does happen, the reason being that the source voltage, until balanced by a capacitor voltage, will continue causing electrons to move irrespective of whether the circuit is open.

The reason an open circuit seems to not have current flow is that the capacitance is very small, and so with very little charge collected on the ends (which happens very quickly) the source voltage is opposed by the voltage across the unconnected ends and the flow of electrons stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons, piled up on the negative terminal of the battery, will, by mutual repulsion, flow to the capacitor plate connected to it, Electrons from the *other* plate will flow to the positive terminal of the battery, which is connected to it and which has an electron deficit. So the flows of electrons *through the wires* at any instant would be as if there were a complete circuit!

Of course the capacitor gives itself away as a capacitor and not a resistor, because the electron flow through the wires soon drops to zero. This is when the pd across the capacitor is equal to the emf of the battery and there is no resultant force driving the electrons through the wires. While charge was flowing there were potential differences across the wires and the battery's internal resistance. Indeed, at the instant the battery was connected there was no potential difference between the capacitor plates so the full battery voltage was driving current through the wires and battery internal resistance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to visualize Philip Wood's explanation.

At the instant the battery is connected to one of the capacitor plates, charge begins to build up on that plate. Assume the battery terminal is (-); then negative charge accumulates on the plate. This produces an electric field which extends across the insulating gap and is "seen" by the conduction electrons in the other plate. In response, they are repelled by the charge on the first plate, and they escape by flowing out the wire connected to their plate. This leaves that plate with a net positive charge; when the magnitude of the negative charge on the first plate is equal to the positive charge on the second plate, this transient current flow stops.

In this way, a capacitor allows short bursts of current (i.e., AC) to flow through it, but prevents the passage of DC.